# VS2008: how to reset to Default project properties in Debug and Release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, reset, project-properties

How I should reset to default the project properties in VS2008, I mean properties of Debug and Release mode.

Comment: *All* properties?  I.e., include paths, library input, etc.? Just create a new project and copy the project file over.  If you don't actually mean all properties then you need to be more specific.  Would it really take that long to just do it by hand?

Comment: Just create a new project and add your files back in.

Comment: @EdS. Right, I guess I have to create a new project.

Comment: Should only take a couple of minutes...